# Audio does not function

Tags: sound

I have installed Kubuntu 20.04 LTS today on my new laptop using Oracle Virtual Machine. The audio does not work in Kubuntu, but it works in Windows.
In the audio menu in Kubuntu, nothing is muted.

Comment: Just to clarify, Windows is the host OS and Kubuntu is a guest on VirtualBox? Did you set up the audio adapter on VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes to all of the above. I installed Google Chrome, and have been playing videos through that . It now works . Thanks for responding.